# polling.js:307 GET https://*****/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Oaxg7sL 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io, http-status-code-404, polling

I am trying to create a simple tic-tac-toe multiplayer game and below is the JS file and HTML file :

`When I run the above code in the VPS , I am getting the below Errors, which says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" . Not sure , if this related to polling error or link issue as it also reflects an 404 issue . I have checked the links and they seem to be working properly. The other alternative I can think of is https.listen to 443 port. I am not very confident on that line to be honest !I have also requested SSL certificate for www, mail, admin and webmail and no issues over there.   [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aG0AT.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOV8M.png)  Please help @jfriend00 !!`

```
index.html:
_______________________________________________________________________________________


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.6.2/socket.io.min.js"></script>


<script>
   ......

    const socket = io("https://*****:443");

 

            socket.emit("find", { name: name })


    socket.on("find", (e) => {



    socket.on("playing", (e) => {
     .......
```

```
___________________________________________________________________________________________
index.js :
____________________________________________________________________________________________
const express=require("express")
const app=express()

const path=require("path")
const https=require("https")
const {Server}=require("socket.io")


const server=https.createServer(app)

const io=require('socket.io-client')
const socket=io("https://clozby.in:443")
app.use(express.static(path.resolve("")))

let arr=[]
let playingArray=[]

io.on("connection",(socket)=>{
    arr=[]
    playingArray=[]

    socket.on("find",(e)=>{

       
                io.emit("find",{allPlayers:playingArray})
    socket.on("playing",(e)=>{
        io.emit("playing",{allPlayers:playingArray})

    socket.on("gameOver",(e)=>{


app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    return res.sendFile("index.html")
})

https.listen(443,"45.130.229.198")=>{
    console.log("port connected to 443")
```